# Immutable variables in RUST can be reassigned using destructuring?

Tags: rust, immutability, destructuring

I was quite surprised to find that the following program will happily compile and run (using "cargo 1.42.0 (86334295e 2020-01-31)."), outputting:

5
k

The variable x which is not declared as mut is not only reassigned but reassigned with a different type.
Is there some reason why you are allowed to do this?

```
fn main() {

    let x = 5;

    println!("{}", x);

    let t: (i32, f64, char) = (2, 3.14, 'k');

    let (_,_,x) = t;

    println!("{}", x);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "shadowing a variable"

(https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing)

It can also been shown as simply as so:

```
let x = 5;
let x = 'k';
```

It actually comes in handy often. For instance, you can reuse an identifier after you are done using its initially assigned value:

```
let two_times_five = 2 * 5; // type i32
let two_times_five = two_times_five.to_string(); // type String
```

The compiler will still enforce strong typing; accesses to `two_times_five` before its redefinition will be accessing an i32, accesses afterward will be accessing a String.

There are also times when you don't want a variable to be mutable, but at some point you want to assign it a different value. Using variable shadowing rather than `let mut` means you know the variable is not changed in between its definitions, regardless of what functions it's passed into or methods are called on it.

Comment: Ah okay thanks! I'm coming from mainly java where you can't really do anything like that.